# How to style the Telerik FilteringDropDown in RadGrid View

Tags: wpf, silverlight, c#-4.0, telerik, expression-blend

I can't find a way to apply my custom styles to the buttons, checkboxes etc. contained in a Popup of **RadGridView** when the filter button is clicked. I would also like to change the popup's background color etc.

[image: Want To Style this dropdown]

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd take a look at [this post](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/silverlight/gridview/filteringdropdown.aspx) on the Telerik forums.

**EDIT :** Ah, OK - the [FilteringControl](http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/radgridview-styles-and-templates-templates-structure.html#FilteringControl) template looks like what you need in that case. Can you not apply the styles to the named sections in there?

Comment: Widor this post refers to the filter symbol but I want to style the popup.

Comment: This looks like the correct way. But I can't figure out how to reference the FilteringControl style OR should it be an implicit style??

Comment: I don't have aything to test it on, but this should guide you: http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/how-to-override-default-gridview-styles.html